# Problems with connecting to local postgres database from R through RPostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql

I have to following code

```
drv <- RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL()
con <- DBI::dbConnect(drv, dbname = 'dbname', user = 'user', 
                      host = 'host.name', port = 5432, password = 'password')
```

When I run it on server (Ubuntu server 16.04 with latest updates) running the database I get the following error:

```
Error in .valueClassTest(ans, "data.frame", "dbGetQuery") :
  invalid value from generic function ‘dbGetQuery’, class “NULL”, expected “data.frame”
```

But when I run R from commandline with sudo, it works, when I run it from different my laptop connecting to the DB on the server it also works. So it shouldn't be connection problem. I am thinking about problem with access rights to some libraries/executables/configs on the system? Any help will be appreciated.

When I run the `dbConnect` multiple times and it ends with the error, when I run `drv_info <- RPostgreSQL::dbGetInfo(drv)`, I still get multiple connectionIds in the `drv_info`:

```
drv_info <- RPostgreSQL::dbGetInfo(drv)
> drv_info
$drvName
[1] "PostgreSQL"

$connectionIds
$connectionIds[[1]]
<PostgreSQLConnection>

$connectionIds[[2]]
<PostgreSQLConnection>

$fetch_default_rec
[1] 500

$managerId
<PostgreSQLDriver>

$length
[1] 16

$num_con
[1] 2

$counter
[1] 2
```

Comment: Also, when I am running the command from rstudio server running on the same server, the connection works.

Comment: Postgres has different authentication mechanisms depending on the originating host. It might be that the hostname you are connecting with resolves to 127.0.0.1 or 127.1.0.1 on the server, which demands that only certain users can connect. Try hard-coding the external IP address.

Comment: I think the problem lies somewhere after connection, because when I try different password (on 127.0.0.1 or external IP) I get different error: 
`Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) :`
`RS-DBI driver: (could not connect username@host on dbname "dbname"`

Comment: Ok ... then you'll really need to show more code: `dbGetQuery` is certainly post-connection, but you don't show what you did to trigger that error.

Comment: These are all the commands I am using (I've updated the parameters I use). Should I try to split the `dbConnect` into more commands, so I can pinpoint more exactly the point of error?

Comment: That's what I don't understand: if you look at the source with [`getMethod(dbConnect, "PqDriver")`](https://github.com/rstats-db/RPostgres/blob/561f5fd0fdc4f4ce47098d45e726930328331a6d/R/connection.R#L61-L77), there is no call to `dbGetQuery`, suggesting something else is being done here. What versions of `RPostgres`, `DBI`, R, and Postgres are you using?

Comment: R version 3.4.0, DBI_0.5-1, RPostgreSQL_0.4-1, Postgres 9.6. This is the config for `sudo`, the user for which it didn't work had DBI_0.6-11. After installing 0.5-1 it worked. It seems I have misconfigured libraries and each user is using different ones. I still don't know the root of the problem, but I have a viable workaround now.

Answer (score 1):

Found a source of confusion, but not necessarily the root problem. (I was assuming [`RPostgres`](https://github.com/rstats-db/RPostgres/), while you are using [`RPostgreSQL`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/rpostgresql/source/default/source) ([github mirror](https://github.com/cran/RPostgreSQL/blob/master/R/PostgreSQLSupport.R#L102-L104)).)

If you check the source, you'll find that the method is calling `postgresqlNewConnection`, which [includes a call to `dbGetQuery`](https://github.com/cran/RPostgreSQL/blob/master/R/PostgreSQLSupport.R#L102-L104). The problem you're seeing is that your call to `dbConnect` is failing (my guess is at [line 100](https://github.com/cran/RPostgreSQL/blob/master/R/PostgreSQLSupport.R#L100)) and returns something unexpected, but `postgresqlNewConnection` continues.

I see three options for you:

- try calling `dbConnect(..., forceISOdate=FALSE)` to bypass that one call to `dbGetQuery` (note that this doesn't fix the connection problem, but it at least will not give you the unexpected query error on connection attempt);
- [raise an issue](https://code.google.com/archive/p/rpostgresql/issues) for the package maintainers; or
- switch to using [`RPostgres`](https://github.com/rstats-db/RPostgres/), still `DBI`-based and actively developed (it looks like `RPostgreSQL` has not had significant commits in the last few years, not sure if that's a sign of good code stability or development stagnation)

One lesson you may take from this is that you should check the value returned from `dbConnect`; if `is.null(con)`, something is wrong. (Again, this does not solve the connection problem.)

Comment: ```forceISOdate=FALSE``` in  is the key!

```con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = 'about_psql',
                 host = 'localhost', port = 5432,
                 user = 'TheDonald', password = 'Tweet!', forceISOdate=FALSE)

```

Comment: oh yes! My intention was only to show my example that was fixed by the "forceISOdate".